# JS - added a button but need help to set his position

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a button with JS to HTML div tag, after adding it I would like to set his position to the right corner:

[image]

But when I added margin-left it dropped down a line.

How can I fix this?

the code:

```
function CheckForm(){
    let form = document.getElementById('fcf-form-id');
    if (form['Email'].value == "") {
        let x = document.getElementById('error-msg');
        const button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        button.innerHTML = 'X';
        x.innerHTML = "I need you to enter you Email in order to get back to you."
        x.appendChild(button);
        button.style.marginLeft ='95%';
        x.setAttribute("style" , "opacity:1");
        button.addEventListener('click' , () => {  x.innerHTML ="";  x.setAttribute("style" , "opacity:0");    } )
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can use `style="float:right"` or use `style="display: inline-block"` or `style="display:inline-flex"`

Answer (score 0):

Set the wrapper to be relative, set the button to be absolute and set the top and left.

```css
.error {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.error .message {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.error .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="error">
<p class="message">
Hello World. It is foo.
</p>
<button class="close">x</close>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you share the code for this. You should ensure you use a reliable scaling ratio like `%` and you may way to set the display attribute of the button to inline-block

```
 display: inline-block;
```

Comment: sure, added to the post